# Why Golang treats my POST request as a GET one?

Tags: ios, http, go

My server code like:

```
// golang
type SomeHandler struct{}

func (*SomeHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("method:", req.Method)
    fmt.Println("content length:", req.ContentLength)

    // read request body as []byte
    content, err := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
    if err != nil {
        // do sth.
        return
    }

    // decode JSON
    // ...
}
```

Client side:

```
// Objective-C on iOS 6/7
// NSURL *myUrl = ...
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:myUrl];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[req setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

id obj = @{
             @"username" : @"myname",
             @"password" : @"mypwd",
          };
NSError *error;
NSData *inputJson = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:obj options:0 error:&error];
if (error) {
    // no error here
}
[req setHTTPBody:inputJson];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        return;
    }

    NSHTTPURLResponse *resp = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    NSString *outputText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"response (%d):\n%@", (int)resp.statusCode, outputText);
}
```

When I run this iOS code in iPhone simulator the server side shows:

```
method: GET
content length: 0
```

Chage my client side code: `[req setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];`, the server works:

```
method: HEAD
content length: <some length>
```

I don't know what's wrong with my POST code on the client or what should I do on the server to retrieve data as []byte my client just sent.

btw,
my go version:

```
$ go version
go version go1.2.1 darwin/amd64
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem is on the Go side? Have you tried different client/server combinations? (e.g. use `curl` to issue a post to your server, or have your client try to post to a netcat listening socket)

Comment: I've just solved the problem. That's so strange!! Check my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this! So strange behavior. I don't know why this could happen.

I register my handler like:

```
// addr := ...
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.Handle("/abc", new(SomeHandler))
http.Handle("/", r)
// here mux is github.com/gorilla/mux
// these lines of code do the same thing as wrote:
//   http.handle("/abc", new(SomeHandler))

err := http.ListenAndServe(addr, nil)
// ...
```

Then my client sends a request to say

```
http://addr:9999//abc
```

But the correct URL should be

```
http://addr:9999/abc
```

The redundant `/` generated when call `-stringByAppendingString:` method.

Comment: It looks like gorilla/mux automatically generates a redirect response for a non-canonical URL.  HTTP clients aren't generally meant to redo a POST in response to a redirect, which would explain the behaviour you observed.

Comment: Yes, there is a new request sends to my server. But it isn't gorilla/mux causes this trouble. The same things happen when write code directly using net/http like `http.Handle("/abc", new(SomeHandler))`

Comment: Similarly I had an unexpected redirect of POST to GET from `http.HandleFunc("/actions/", actionsHandler)`, and the fix was trailing slash removal `http.HandleFunc("/actions", actionsHandler)`.